# iAd banner is fetched but not visible

Tags: swift, iad

I'm trying to make iAd banner. Console says that banner is loaded and fetched successfully, but I can't see it in the simulator. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var banner : ADBannerView = ADBannerView()
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
{
banner.delegate = self
banner.alpha = 0.0

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "bannerViewDidLoadAd", name: "banner", object: nil)
}

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    println("banner tries to load")
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    println("banner successfully fetched")
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {banner.alpha = 1.0})
    UIView.commitAnimations()

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    println("banner is closed")
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("banner failed too! Man...")
    println(error.localizedDescription)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {banner.alpha = 1.0})
}
```

in GameScene:

```
func iBanner() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("banner", object: nil)
}

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    iBanner()
 }
```

Comment: Where are you setting your `ADBannerView`'s size and position?

Comment: Ehm. Nowhere. I thought it is optional. Do I need to?

Comment: @DanielStorm I did it and nothing changed, banner is still invisible.

Comment: could you update your code to show where your banner is